# Calculate average of any two numbers in a given array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was asked this question in an interview. I was unable to solve it.

Suppose we an have array `let arr = [4,5,10,9,8]`.

Write a code in JavaScript to print numbers that are greater than the average of any two elements of the given array.

Suppose I decide to calculate the average of 5 & 9. The average would be 7. So the answer would be numbers greater than 7 i.e 8 9 & 10 should print on the console.

NOTE- We have to find the average of any two elements and then check, not the average of all the numbers.
Can someone please help with the logic?

Comment: do you have a result?

Comment: Result depends on the numbers you choose for calculating average.

Comment: Can you show the result for this input [4,5,10,9,8]

Comment: Suppose i decide to calculate average of 5 & 9. Average would be 7. So the answer would be numbers greater than 7 i.e 8 9 & 10 should print on the console.

Comment: @Developer_06 Add those details to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don' know if this will help you:

```js
let arr = [4,5,10,9,8]
arr.sort((a,b) => a-b)    // sorted array

function greaterThanAverage(x,y){
    let average = (x+y)/2
    let index = arr.findIndex(e => e > average )
    return arr.slice(index == -1 ? arr.length : index)
}

console.log(greaterThanAverage(5,9))
console.log(greaterThanAverage(10,9))
console.log(greaterThanAverage(5,4))
console.log(greaterThanAverage(30,4))
```

Comment: This solution is working. Can we also implement it using 2 for loops?

Answer (score 0):

For me, it looks like you could get only two results:

- No result if two max values are the same, so no value is greater than the average.
- Only the greatest value if a next smaller value exists.

---

Another solution could be to select a pair and filter the array basex on the average of the pair.

```js
const
    values = [4, 5, 10, 9, 8];

for (let i = 0, l = values.length - 1; i < l; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < values.length; j++) {
        const average = (values[i] + values[j]) / 2;
        console.log(values[i], values[j], '|', average, '|', ...values.filter(v => v > average));
    }
}
```

Comment: So we cannot calculate average of any two elements?

Comment: i have the problem with the word **any**. what does it mean to you?

Comment: I think  he is talking about that we can consider all pairs averages and the current number should be greater than at least one of them

Answer (score 0):

So according to the problem we have to display all numbers which are greater than any average of two elements.

So it's better to choose the two smallest elements in the array and find all the numbers which are greater than their average.

```js
function solve(arr) {
    arr.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b });
    let firstMinimum = arr[0];
    let secondMinimun = arr[1];
    let avg = (firstMinimum + secondMinimun) / 2;

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > avg) console.log(arr[i]);
    }
}
solve([4, 5, 10, 9, 8]);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is O(n) solution.
find min and secondMin, take average and it will give you min average.

```
    const values = [4, 5, 10, 9, 8];
    const minValue = Math.min(...values);
    values.splice(values.indexOf(minValue),1);
    const secondMinValue = Math.min(...values);
    const minAverage = (minValue + secondMinValue)/2;
    const result = values.filter(val => val > minAverage);
```